# How can I create custom underline or highlight for text in html or css?

Tags: html, css, text, underline

I'm trying to figure out how to create a custom background effect for text.
In other words, how can I make something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the [<mark> element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/mark) and tweek the line-height

```css
mark {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0em;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<h1><mark>Lorem ipsum</mark></h1>
```

Comment: I only recently learned this element even existed. Now I know why :)

Comment: @somethinghere me to! I just had to go trough [this list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element) a few days ago. The list ain't that big but good to know...

Comment: I found out through htmlreference.io not so long ago as well. It sounds like a deprecated element, reminding me of `marquee`. Also, turns out I'm old enough to think that...

Comment: Any idea how to get that working on multiline headlines?

Answer (score 9):

A very good article explains a nice way to do that with gradients: https://thirtyeightvisuals.com/blog/low-highlight-heading-links-squarespace

```css
.highlight {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg,rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%, #FFD0AE 50%);
}
```

Comment: The mentioned site isn't working anymore.

Answer (score 2):

For these I usually use an SVG pixel (a 1x1  stretchable HTML-encoded SVG with a fill color) that we can manoeuvre anyway we want:

```css
h1 {
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' x='0px' y='0px' width='1px' height='1px' viewBox='0 0 1 1' preserveAspectRatio='none'%3E%3Crect x='0' y='0' width='1' height='1' fill='red' /%3E%3C/svg%3E") no-repeat 100% 100%;
  background-size: 100% 50%;
}
```

```html
<h1>My Text</h1>
```

This also allows for animations to be easily added. This only works on single-line items, however. You can change the color inside the `svg fill` property. If encoded it works on IE9+, so it's pretty compatible! Just remember that the hash sign in front of hex colors needs to be encoded as well - its `%23` (personally I use sass to encode it for me).

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this using a linear-gradient set to the background property.

CSS

```
.low-highlight {
  background:linear-gradient(180deg, transparent 60%, yellow 60%);
}
```

HTML

```
<p>You can easily <span class="low-highlight">do underline</span> me.</p>
```

```css
p {
font-size:68px;
  font-weight:600;
  font-family:'Merriweather';
}


.low-highlight {
  background:linear-gradient(180deg, transparent 60%, yellow 60%);
}
```

```html
<p>You can easily <span class="low-highlight">do underline</span> me.</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try resizing the line size. Line-height. And then highlight the text.

Comment: Whats `line-size`? And how does `line-height` affect this? It does neither.